# What's the equivalent SQL code for this hashing code in Java (Scala)

Tags: java, postgresql, scala

I have the following Scala code that is hashing user password:

```
val digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
val hash = new String(digest.digest (password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).getBytes
```

I want to do the same in my PostgresSQL server using SQL.

I have tried

```
digest(password, 'sha256')
```

didn't work, I am guessing it is because of the `getBytes` call in java, we are digesting the bytes of the strings and not the string itself (if it even make any sense!)

what is the equivalent of `getBytes` for Postgress SQL ? if it exists ?

Thank you.

**CONTEXT**
I am just trying to make a query that will insert a user manually for ease of testing, it is inserting but I can't log in. the digest generated by my query and by the scala code is not the same.

Comment: It's actually a good thing that the hash is different for `1962` and `password`.

Comment: @Kayaman, that was an example :D , let me edit

Comment: The `digest()` will convert it to bytes too, don't worry. Hashes are created from bytes, not from characters. You do need to make sure you're using the same encoding though, otherwise more exotic characters won't be turned into the same bytes.

Comment: @Kayaman , but it is not giving the same hash generated by scala, that's what is strange

Comment: Probably because you're trying to convert the hash into a String. Hashes are bytes, not Strings. `digest.digest (password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))` is all you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

```
val hash = new String(digest.digest (password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).getBytes
```

That's wrong. You're hashing the password properly, then for some reason you turn the bytes into a String...only to turn it back to bytes again. That's unnecessary, stupid, and will most likely corrupt things.

```
val hash = digest.digest (password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

There's your hash in bytes.

To mimic your broken code try `convert_from(digest(password, 'sha256'), 'UTF8')::bytea` and see if you get the same results.

Comment: I completely agree, but that has been in prod for over two years now. and if I would change it all old users won't be able to log in. so I am looking for a way around that.

Comment: So you're looking for a way to implement a broken hashing mechanism in Postgres? You could possibly try to cast the results of `digest` back to `text` and back to `bytea`, that's what the code is doing so maybe you'll be lucky and get the same result.

Comment: I am so ashamed to say so, but yes :D

Comment: Thanks for the help. any standard way for casting in postgres?

Comment: There are standard casts (with `::` being the shorthand), but you should use the `convert_from` function. See my edit in the answer.

Comment: That worth the shot, but it didn't work. `invalid byte sequence in utf-8` 
Thanks again for the help, and cheer up ;)

Comment: That sucks, because guess what... `new String(hash, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` **doesn't** cause an exception. It just converts the unmappable bytes into replace characters. So you are going to have to modify that code of yours.